# Unexpected EOF during reading

Tags: c++, ifstream

I wrote two files, one in text mode and one in binary mode with the following code:

### write.cpp

```
struct person {
    char name[20];
    int age;
    float weight;
};

int main(){

    ofstream output("data.txt");
    ofstream output2("data2.txt", ios::out|ios::binary);

    int i;
    person tmp;
    for (i=0; i<4; i++){
        cout<<"Write name: ";
        cin >> tmp.name;
        cout<<endl<<"age: ";
        cin >> tmp.age;
        cout<<endl<<"weight: ";
        cin >> tmp.weight;

        output.write((char*) &tmp, sizeof(tmp));
        output2.write((char*) &tmp, sizeof(tmp));
    }


    output.close();
    output2.close();

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

The 2 files are identically (I checked also with an hex editor).

When i try to read with the following code, i get a EOF after reading the first item:

### read.cpp

```
int main(){
    bool found = false;
    int pos;
    person tmp;
    ifstream file("data.txt");

    if (!file) {
        cout << "Error";
        return 1;
    }

    while(!file.eof() && !found) {
        file.read( (char*) &tmp, sizeof(tmp));
        cout << "tmp.name: "<<tmp.name<<endl;
        cout << "EOF? "<<file.eof()<<endl;
        if (strcmp(tmp.name, "jack") == 0){
            found = true;
            //pos = file.tellg();
            //pos -= (int) sizeof(tmp);
        }
    }

    file.close();
    cout << endl <<"Press ENTER to continue...";
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

### output

```
tmp.name: Jacob
EOF? 1
found? 0
```

But if I open the ifstream into binary mode ( `ifstream file("data.txt", ios::in|ios::binary);` ) the program finds the person I wanted to search.
Can someone explain me why it works in binary mode even if i wrote the file in text mode?

Comment: The actual difference between binary and text mode differs depending on your OS and your C++ library, neither of which you specify in your question.  In general, trying to read binary data from a file opened in text mode will result in undefined behavior.

Comment: So the "problem" is that the read/write methods **always** work in binary mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't say what OS you're under, so I can only speculate, but
since text and binary modes are identical under Unix, it's
probably Windows.  Under Windows, text mode does two
transformations: it converts a single `'\n'` to a two character
CRLF line ending, and on input, it treats a 0x1A as an end of
file.  From your description, I would guess that your data
contains no 0x0A byte (which would be treated as a `'\n'`),
since the hex comparisons are identical, but that it does
contain a 0x1A byte, which is interpreted as end of file.

More generally, the formal rules for text files is that they can
only contain printable characters, `'\t'` and `'\n'` and that
there is no white space immediately preceding a `'\n'`; in
addition, it is implementations defined whether a final `'\n'`
is required or not.  In sum, you cannot write binary data to
a file opened in text mode, and expect to reread it.

Also, the layout of a `struct` and the representation of the
fundamental types is implementation defined, and may (and
sometimes does) change from one version to another.  Which means
that if you simply use `ostream::write`, you can't be sure of
begin able to reread the data in the future (and no other
program can ever be sure of rereading it).  There's a reason why
the argument to `ostream::write` is `char const*`, and not `void
const*`; `ostream::write` it to be used to write data you have
formatted yourself (perhaps in a binary format like XDR); not to
dump memory byte by byte to the file.

And finally, in the `read` process: using `file.eof()` in the
loop condition is an error.  And using the results of
`istream:read` without first ensuring that it worked is
undefined behavior.  You're loop should probably be
something along the lines of:

```
Person tmp;
while ( file.read( ... ) && strcmp( tmp.name, "jack" ) != 0 ) {
    //  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1)

> Can someone explain me why it works in binary mode even if i wrote the file in text mode?

According to you, the files are exactly the same when you looked at them in a hex editor, so  in this case it doesn't matter whether you wrote them in binary mode or text mode.  Generally, in text mode there will be *secret-and-behind-your-back* conversions of newlines from one byte to two bytes on Windows.

2) You should never use file.eof() as the while conditional when reading a file--it's too persnickety.  Instead, you should use your read statement as the conditional:

```
while(file.read( (char*) &tmp, sizeof(tmp)) && !found)
```

Your program works with that while conditional.

3) Your cast:

```
(char*)
```

is a C cast.  You should really use the much uglier C++ cast:

```
reinterpret_cast<char*>(&tmp)
```

which you can think of as a big neon sign indicating something really crazy is happening.

Comment: Well about 1): i agree with you, but the program works only if i open the file in binary mode, and i can't understand why..

about 2): i tried with that condition befor using the eof() but still it doesn't work. (actually it works..but, again,  only in binary mode)

about 3): i didn't know that!

Comment: Are you running your program on Windows?

Comment: Yes, I'm on Win7 64bit and i use GCC 4.6.2

Comment: @user2340612 The fact that he needs a `reinterpret_cast` (and that a C style cast resolves to a `reinterpret_cast` is a sign that the code isn't portable, and isn't guaranteed to work.  (But that's _not_ the problem with his code, since he has probably compiled both programs with the same compiler, using the same options, and is running them on the same machine.)